# Is Northwest the wrong spelling

Tags: capitalization, transatlantic-differences, ielts

I am taking IELTS exam and I was marked wrong in the following question:

> 5. Preferred location: in the **Northwest**

Apparently, the correct answer is "North-West."

Notice that officially, IELTS supposed to support both British spelling and American spelling. For example, both "color" and "colour" should be marked correct. I check the Merriam-Webster dictionary and I am pretty confident my spelling is the correct American way of spelling. [According to Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/northwest),

> **northwest**, capitalized: regions or countries to the northwest of a specified or implied point of orientation.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/northwest NB It's _vegetarian_ and _Merriam_.

Comment: Hi, would you expand on it?I checked the link and it is not very clear to me when to use the capitalization and when not to. More importantly, even northwest would be markded wrong by IELTS. There is only one correct answer and that is North-West

Comment: IMO you would only capitalise north-west when it is part of a proper name as The Northwest Territories of Canada. You have overlooked that the Merriam-Webtser entry says "**North West** geographical name" below the uncapitalised definitions.

Comment: *IELTS **is** supposed to support both British spelling and American spelling.* I can only assume that as the context is for a stay in the UK and it is on a British English form, "North-West" is what is required as this is the British term, although it seems a little harsh unless context has been given.

Comment: The exam you quote says nothing about regions or countries. In fact, the use of ***in*** *the northwest* strongly suggests the adverbial definition, which is all lowercase, rather than the common noun sense you propose. But since the exam provides no context for the phrase, it's impossible to say.

Comment: As only one line of your screenshot was relevant, I have removed it and used text for the relevant portion. Again, screenshots are a broadly unfriendly way of displaying text unless you write out suitable "alt" text, and if you're going through the trouble to do that, you might as well just enter it directly. Generally, images on this site should be reserved for things like illustrations, photographs with objects to identify, and other things which cannot be represented in text form.

Comment: @Greybeard in the context of filling in a British English form I can fill in anything at all, because I am the one doing the filling in. Nobody at all will stop me from staying in the UK just because I can't spell a word. Frankly they'd have to kick out 99% of their own population first.

Comment: Ask someone who lives in Oregon.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Three points arise: 1. You are not filling in a form, you are doing an exam. 2. I have stated that it is an assumption and that it seems harsh, but I can think of no other explanation. 3. If on a US visa application you entered your destination as "Northwestern Territories", I assure you that you would not get the visa.